# absolute value of function in fractional Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

$$
H^s_p=\left\{f\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d):\  (1-\Delta)^{s/2} f\in L^p, \ p>1\right\} . 
$$
$$
\|f\|_{H^s_p}:=\|(1-\Delta)^{s/2} f\|_p. 
$$
Let $\rho\geq 0, \rho\in C^\infty_c$,$\int\rho=1$ and $\rho_n(x)=n^d \rho(nx)$.

My Question is: suppose $f\in \cap_{s\geq 0}H_p^s,\ \ f_n(x)=f*\rho_n(x)=\int f(x-y)\rho_n(y)\ dy$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$,  is the following inequality: 
$$
\| \ \  {|f_n|} \ \  \|_{H^{-\alpha}_p}\leq C \|f\|_{H^{-\alpha}_p} \ \ \ \left(\mbox{or}\  \leq C \|f\|_{H^{-\beta}_q}\\  \mbox{for some suitable index}\  \beta<1, \ q>1.\right)
$$
reasonable? And how to prove it?

Comment: How do you define your norme?

Comment: The $H^s_p$-norm is defined by $$\|f\|_{H^s_p}= \|(1-\Delta)^{s/2} f\|_p. $$